# Jquery/JavaScript code binding to collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically generated table of records and for each row, I have an anchor tag with class name set to 'hdelete' to enable me invoke delete method on the particular row's link that is clicked. I have some code currently that is support to hook up all the anchors with class ='hdelete'

```
  $("#tbl_srecords").click(function (e) {
       $(e.target).hasClass("hdelete") ? fnDeletehrecord($(e.target)) : null; //Run the delte row function here
    });
```

The code above does not seem to work. what it currently does is select just the first occurence of anchor with class='hdelete'.  Anyone with a better idea on how to best implement this?

Comment: Please do not abuse the `?:` operator like this. JavaScript (and pretty much every other language) has `if()` for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will bind a function to all anchor tags with class hdelete and call the fnDeletehrecord function with the element as a jquery object past as a parameter.

```
   $("#tbl_srecords a.hdelete").click(function(){
       //NOTE: This represents the anchor tag that fired the event
       fnDeletehrecord($(this));
    });
```

Comment: I think you didn't notice the line `I have a dynamically generated table`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera I did notice that, however the poster did not specify where the content was dynamically generated, it could have been server side.  I also figured that if click was firing the function in his original code he may not need binding on dynamic content.  Also didn't want to snake your answer.

Answer (score 2):

`I have a dynamically generated table`

```
$("#tbl_srecords a.hdelete").live('click', function (e) {
    fnDeletehrecord($(this)); // pass the element as a parameter to the function
});
```

`live` is Deprecated

This is latest (recommended)

```
$("#tbl_srecords").on('click', 'a.hdelete', function (e) {
    fnDeletehrecord($(this)); // pass the element as a parameter to the function
});
```

because of dynamic content.

Comment: Shouldn't the element be passed to the function as a jquery object?

Comment: Anytime, glad to help.  Like the use of .on() +1

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("#tbl_srecords a.hdelete").click(fnDeletehrecord);
```

This code will handle click events on the links with class `hdelete` within element with id `tbl_srecords`.